# How do i display my code with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I wanted to try something simple today with jQuery, but it doesn't seem to display anything on the page, whatever i try.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <style type="text/css">
     div{
      height:100px;
      width:100px;
      background-color:#FF0000;
      border-radius:5px;
     }
    </style>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $('div').fadeOut(1000);
     });
    </script>
   </head>
  <body>
   <div>
   </div>   
  </body>
 </html>
```

Fixed it. I just forgot to put the jQuery script in it.

Comment: missing references to jquery maybe ?

Comment: Your div is empty put something there. And missing jquery reference

Comment: you did not included jquery.js file in <head> tag

Comment: yes, if you put something in the div you will see that fade out as you have requested in your code. Once you add the jquery lib as well.

Comment: Why ppl still answer this kind qustion ? earn more rep. ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be including jquery. Try adding this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, but its result isn't visible.

Your jQuery code makes your div slowly disappear. But the said div is empty, so it is invisible.

Put something into your div and you'll see some results !

Also, don't forget to include the jQuery source.

Comment: Thanks, but everything works. It was indeed the jQuery source that was missing.